# How to put text side by side with image inside div?

Tags: html, css

in my div(container) i want to have long text side by side with image.
I tried with float left/right didnt work, when i use margin-top it is not good because all images/text are not the same height/lenght.

```css
.containerpost{
  margin-left: 25px;
  width: 40%;
  background: white;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  overflow: hidden;
  clear: both;
}

.description{
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
.avatar{
  float: right;
  height: 200px;
  clear: both;
  margin-top: -0%;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove all floats and try out flexbox. By applying `display: flex;` to the container the 2 items inside (image and div with text) will sit side by side. The `align-items: center` rule makes sure they are vertically centered.

I have removed other styles that seemed to not be relevant. Feel free to add back whatever you need.

```css
.containerpost {
  background: white;
  border-radius: 4px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.avatar {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerpost">
  <div class="description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed congue dolor id urna laoreet ullamcorper. Vestibulum vel metus quis ipsum blandit tincidunt.</div>
  <img class="avatar" src="https://picsum.photos/200" />
</div>
```